# mod_rewrite rule to change URL

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

How could I create rewrite rule in the file .htaccess to change this URL:

```
http://www.benessereglobale.net/beta/shtml/home.shtml
```

into this:

```
http://www.benessereglobale.net/home.shtml
```

Thanks

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /base
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule  /beta/(.*) /beta/shtml/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule  /beta/shtml/(.*) /beta/$1 [L,R=302]

</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home.shtml$ /beta/shtml/home.shtml [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /beta/shtml/$1 [L]
```